# I have some problems with updating my bot from v11 to v12

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make a discord bot but I have some problems updating my bot from v11 to v12.
I need help by my kick and ban code
this is my Kick code

```
        var member= message.mentions.members.first();

    member.kick().then((member) => {

         message.channel.send(member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked :point_right: ");
    }).catch(() => {

            message.channel.send("Access Denied");
        });
    }
}
```

and ban

```
        var member= message.mentions.members.first();

        member.ban().then((member) => {

            message.channel.send(member.displayName + " has been successfully banned");
        }).catch(() => {

            message.channel.send("Access Denied");
        });
    }
}
```

and I couldn't find it on https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#before-you-start

Comment: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html

Comment: You didn't declared what's you problem.

Comment: it just wont work i get no error or other something

Comment: looks correct to me, have you tested the commands? any errors?
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban